# SQL Conditional Insert or update statement depending on a pair of columns. Using unique index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, conditional-statements

OK so I have a table (in my MySQL database) as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `funddata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticker` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `price_date` date NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

And some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO funddata (ticker, price_date, price) VALUES ("tick1", '2013-06-01', 36.2);
INSERT INTO funddata (ticker, price_date, price) VALUES ("tick2", '2013-06-01', 14.7);
INSERT INTO funddata (ticker, price_date, price) VALUES ("tick3", '2013-06-01', 102.5);
INSERT INTO funddata (ticker, price_date, price) VALUES ("tick1", '2013-07-01', 38.7);
INSERT INTO funddata (ticker, price_date, price) VALUES ("tick2", '2013-07-01', 16.2);
```

---

Now let's say I want to add some more prices for `tick1`. If the price I want to add already exists in my table for that date then I want to update what's there with the new price, else I just want to insert it as a new record.

Does it make sense to make a unique index out of (`ticker`, `price_date`) given that no 2 records should share the same ticker and date? If so how would I do this and how would I make use of such an index.

Comment: you can create a primary key on (id and date) and use "insert on duplicate key update"

Comment: Normalise your db is even better.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON funddata(priceDate, price);
```

Then use `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

But still,this break the first normal form.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Thanks for your answer, should I actually make the index on `ticker` and `price_date`? As one can might records that share the same price and date but each date should only occur once per ticker. E.g. `tick1` should only have one record for `2013-06-01`...

Comment: Also, from reading about the 1st normal form, I don't beleive this method violates it as there is still only 1 "atomic" value in each field; I'm not trying to divide fields into parts.